# Helping users add context to their questions

Tags: discussion

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88691/solution-for-rod-cutting-problem-using-dynamic-programming

Sometimes, users posts a programming problem as the title of their question, followed by their solution and very little else. Now, a bit of Google-fu on the title itself points me to [this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-13-cutting-a-rod/), and as much as I am inclined to just include the link in the question, I think that should be left to the OP. In other words, we shouldn't be encouraging laziness on the OP's part by helping them include links or descriptions to the programming problems.

Am I taking a reasonable stand here, or should I be more flexible? I'm pointing out this question specifically as it is down to -4 at time of writing, and I'm not sure if that's all because it's missing just a link to the programming problem.

On a related note, how about solutions to the more familiar Project Euler problems? Should OP always be compelled to link to the source of their programming problem?

TSP = Travelling Salesman Problem, and we even have a tag [travelling-salesman](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travelling-salesman) for it, but I genuinely did not know without looking at the tags for this question: [Genetic Algorithm for TSP](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88744/genetic-algorithm-for-tsp). I'll file this the same as "familiar Project Euler problems"...

Comment: Note that this is [not the first offense](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) for this user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In other words, we shouldn't be encouraging laziness on the OP's part by helping them include links or descriptions to the programming problems.

I agree. It is not your responsibility to add the description, it is the responsibility of the OP.

I think the most helpful thing to do is to add a comment and ask for more description. If the OP ignores those comments, then that is up to them.

That being said, if the question is on the risk of being closed because the lack of description, and it is a question you really really want to post a review to, then you should feel free to add description.

Project Euler problems are easier to know the description of as they are easily google-able if you know the id number of the problem. However, it is **always** strongly recommended to include a description of the problem in the question itself, and a link to the original source. A while ago, Project Euler was offline, which caused all their own descriptions of the problems to be unavailable. The general Stack Exchange policy is to not rely on links.